# passing data from view to controller from dynamically added form fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to asp.net mvc can any one say how exactly i need to pass data from dynamically created fields to to model list in view to controller. 
i'm following dynamically created form fields from below link

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/XaXB0